# How to remove deleted webpage returning 200 from indexers?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, google-index, bing, 410-gone

I have recently deleted my personal webpage - cancelled the entire hosting and gave up the domain.
I want the Bing, google and others to remove the pages from their indexes. However, my hosting provider does not return 404 or 410 codes when trying to access the pages. It returns a 200 with a message saying something like "This domain is blocked".
Now the Bing for example explicitly asks for either 404 or 410 to be able to remove the page through their content removal tool.
What can I do to remove the page from indexes?

Answer (score 2):

At this point, your best bet is probably re-purchasing the domain and removing all DNS records. This way search engines (and users) won't be able to access anything; it will be as if nothing exists.

This is the easiest & cheapest way to kill off a website. Keeping the domain registered (which costs relatively little) also stops someone else from jumping on and starting their own website with your existing domain.